# Submit Button Won't Be Enabled When Form is Filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just tried this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/) for a smooth form control. But I couldn't get that working. The submit but remains disabled. I guess textareas were included as input as well.

```js
(function() { // fiddle
    $("form > input").keyup(function() {
        var empty = false;
        $("form > input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Contact">
    <h1> Contact Form </h1>
    <p> Please fill in the form to send message to the site administrator </p>
    <br/>
</div>
<form name="msg" method="post">
    <div id="form" align=center>
        <ul id="items">
            <li align=center>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or Real Name" class="textField" />
            </li>
            <li align=center>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="textField" />
            </li>
            <li align=center>
                <textarea name="content" class="textField" id="content" placeholder="Your Message..."></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="textField" id="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what it looks like when filled:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `form > input` = all `<input>` elements which are a direct child of a `<form>` element

Comment: BUMP,I'm still unable to fix that.There are no solutions yet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42560146/402037

Answer (score 0):

ok, your selector is wrong.

```
 form > selected
```

change to;

```
form > #form > #items > li > input
```

or you can simply use input class selector which is "textField"

Comment: Just tried that out.You're not wrong but I think there's another problem which causes that to not run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working snippet, just look at the jQuery selectors, it works with textareas as well.

```js
(function() {
    $('form > input, form > textarea').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input, form > textarea').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Username<br />
    <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" /><br />
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="password" /><br />
    Confirm Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />    
    Textarea<br />
    <textarea id="v_pass_input" name="v_password"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<div id="test">
</div>
```